# Convert my dynamic path for images with Webpack

Tags: html, typescript, webpack

I'm creating dynamic list of my items from json list on http://localhost:5000/api/laptops. I want to load photos by **laptop.IconFileName** to my path in component.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 item-menu" *ngFor="let laptop of laptops">
                  <span class="helper"></span>


                  <img src="'../../content/Laptop/' + laptop.iconFileName" />
                  <p class="name-menu">
                      {{laptop.name}}

                  </p>
              </div>
```

When i do this dynamicly like above, i got error in Network section:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/content/Laptop/2_apple.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

and my path looks like:

[image]

and when i load manually, i mean: '../../content/Laptop/1_laptop.jpg' in component it works and i'm getting this path:

[image]

I'm using Angular2 SPA with .NET as backend. my app is using webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, webpack resolves your files during build time. It doesn‘t support resolving dynamically during runtime

One thing you can do, is to put the files manually or during build via ‚copy-webpack-plugin‘ into your servers directory and build the urls manually.

Or require all your files and put them in an array and use an object with the dynamic part as the key and the path to the file as the value.

```
const computer1 = require(...);
const icons = {
  computer1,
  ...
};

<img src={icons[laptop.iconFilename]} />
```